# What produces this margin in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have recently upgraded crystal reports to the latest version, and some margins appear to have been introduced.  i've included a picture - this is the report preview.  What are these dotted lines? (they only appear top and left)

The page setup is set to A4 and 0 for all margins

[image]

Some extra information.  If I print out from the original version, and print out from this newer version, everything on the page has been shifted down by about half a cm (the same size as that top margin essentially)

I can make the lines disappear and reappear by toggling Freeze Pane

Page Setup Screen:

[image]

Layout Tab under Options

[image]

Comment: Probably guidelines.  Look for little, gray pentagons in the margins in design mode.

Comment: They aren't guidelines no - I tried that. The margin above and to the left of them appear to come from nowhere. The actual page from the designer starts AT the dotted lines...so the margin is a mystery

Comment: I can make the lines disappear and reappear by toggling Freeze Pane

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded Crystal probably reset your options to display guidelines in Preview mode. Head to "File" → "Options" → In the upper right of the window, deselect "Guidelines" under the "Preview" section.

Otherwise, Crystal will print those dotted lines anywhere you have horizontal or vertical guidelines placed in the Design view ruler.

Comment: They aren't guidelines no - I tried that.  The margin above and to the left of them appear to come from nowhere.  The actual page from the designer starts AT the dotted lines...so the margin is a mystery

Comment: @Paul Could you post an image of your report's Page Setup screen and the Layout tab under Options?

Comment: Is there a private window we could move it to?  It's not something I can put up publically

Comment: @Paul Just post the windows, not anything from the report itself. There shouldn't be any identifying info in those two windows at all.

Comment: I've posted those two windows

Comment: @Paul If the designer page starts at the dotted line it would seem to me like a page size issue... maybe? Just for fun, check the "Dissociate Formatting Page Size..." check box and see what happens. Also, this is CR 2013?